# How to check if tr is show/hide based on dropdown selection

Tags: javascript, jquery

I   have  selection tag  with three options:important,middle important,  not  so  important;  and on each  selection  I  want  to   show  only  those elements from my  table  which  contains  this data.

On the  other   hand  I  want  to  add  logic  which  will tell me  that  certain tr  is  show  or  hide ( I want  to  add  showed  materials  to array)

Here is  my  code  , how   should   I implement  this  logic?

```
<select id="mySelector" class="styled-select slate" style="width:280px; height:35px">
           <option value='important'>აირჩიე</option>
           <option value='very important'>very important</option>
           <option value='middle important'>middle important</option>
           <option value='not so important'>not so important</option>
   </select>

    //selection code
    $(document).ready(function($) {


        $('#mySelector').change( function(){
          var selection = $(this).val();
          $('table')[selection? 'show' : 'hide']();

          if (selection) {
            $.each($('#myTable tbody tr'), function(index, item) {
              $(item)[$(item).is(':contains('+ selection  +')')? 'show' : 'hide']();
            });
          }

        });
    });

    $scope.selectAll = function(){
    document.querySelector('#myTable1').style.display = 'block';

    for (var i = 0; i < $scope.realJsonArray.length; i++) {
      var item = $scope.realJsonArray[i];
      console.log(item.id+"id======================");
       issync1(item);}
    };
    <tr  id="input1">
      <td><input type="checkbox" ng-change="sync(selected[item.id],item)"  ng-checked="isChecked(item.id)" name="checkData" ng-model="selected[item.id]" ng-false-value="undefined" /></td> 
      <td>{{item.id}}</td>
      <td>{{item.organizationNameEN}}</td>
      <td>{{item.organizationNameGE}}</td>   
      <td>{{item.priority}}</td>                   
      <td><button class="btn btn-default btn-xs" ng-click="toggle($index)"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-eye-open"></span></button></td>
    </tr>
```

p.s  my  table  tag  id  is  myTable1

Answer (score 1):

You can use `$.toggleClass()`:

```js
$(function() {
  $('input').on('change', function(e) {
    $('p').toggleClass('hide', this.checked);
  });
});
```

```css
.hide {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<label><input type='checkbox'/>Show/Hide</label>
<p>This is para</p>
```

> function which will tell me if row is selected ( if it is selected it
>   can return true and false in other way for example)

Yes, you can lookup using input checkbox which you have for each row.

**Option 1:** finding using checkboxes itself

```js
$(function() {
  $('button').on('click', function() {
    var rows = $('input[name=checkData]:checked').parents('tr');
    console.log('checked rows', 0 !== rows.length);
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tr id='input1'>
    <td>
      <input name="checkData" type='checkbox' />
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr id='input2'>
    <td>
      <input name="checkData" type='checkbox' checked='' />
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr id='input3'>
    <td>
      <input name="checkData" type='checkbox' />
    </td>
  </tr>
</table><button>Check</button>
```

Comment: hi @Arvind, tahnk  you  for  your  reply,  by  the   way  do   you know how  can  i check  if  raw   is checked   i  mean  can i  use  any  function  which  will tell me   if row  is  selected (  if  it  is  selected  it  can return   true and  false  in  other way  for  example)

Answer (score 1):

Refer following code may this would meet you requirement !!

```
  <table>
    <tr><td></td><td>id</td> <td>name</td> <td>address</td> <td>classA</td> <td>classB</td></tr>  
    <tr ng-repeat="employee in employees">
        <td><input type="checkbox" ng-model="employee.checked" ng-true-value="1" ng-false-value="0"></td>
        <td>{{employee.id}}</td>
        <td>{{employee.name}}</td>
        <td>{{employee.address}}</td>
        <td><input type="checkbox" ng-model="employee.classA"></td>
        <td><input type="checkbox" ng-model="employee.classB"></td>
    </tr>
    </table>


app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope) {


    $scope.employees = [
    { id:"1", name: "A",              address: "A1",    classA: true,  classB: true  },
    { id:"2", name: "B",            address: "A2",    classA: false, classB: true  },
    { id:"3", name: "C",            address: "A3",    classA: true, classB: false  },
    { id:"4", name: "D",             address: "A4",   classA: false, classB: true  },
    { id:"5", name: "E",             address: "A5",   classA: false, classB: true  },
];  

$scope.getSelected = function () {
  var ar = $scope.employees.filter(
    function (value) {
      if (value.checked == 1) {
        return true;
      } else {
        return false;
      }
    }
    );
  return ar;
};

});
```